# Merge a Git fork without changing master branch

Tags: git

My up-to-date branch is *master* (commit M). I had to create the branch *old* from an old commit (commit O1) and make some commits on *old* (commit O3). Now, I want to merge *old* on *master* to save it, but I want to keep the last commit on *master* as it is right now (commit M).

How can I do this?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace may help.

Comment: "I want to create a merge commit without creating any commits. How?" Sorry, no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to that :

- in git, a commit is identified by a hash, which will change if (among others) its parents change.

With this point of view : if you introduce something that merges together `master` and `old`, you can't have the same hash as your current commit on `master`, you will always *create a new commit object*.

- regarding a commit's *content*, however, you can choose to store whatever content you see fit.

With this in mind : you can create a merge commit (one which will have two parents : your current `master` and `old`), but which has the exact same content as your current `master`.

There actually is an option to `git merge` to do exactly that :

```
# from branch 'master' :
git checkout master

# create a merge commit, but ignore all changes that come from 'old' :
git merge -s ours old
```

---

Here is a link to the list of built-in [merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies), here is the section about `ours` :

> **ours**
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the `-Xours` option to the **recursive** merge strategy.

the [Examples section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_examples) contains :

> - Merge branch `obsolete` into the current branch, using `ours` merge strategy:
>
> ```
> $ git merge -s ours obsolete
> ```